# What is the alternative to ls --time-style=full-iso in BSD?

Tags: bsd, ls

command in Linux

```
$ ls -lt --time-style=full-iso
```

output

```
...
-rw-r--r--  1 mduda mduda   1855 2009-08-26 13:07:55.000000000 +0200 screen-configurations.xml
drwxr-xr-x  2 mduda mduda   4096 2009-08-26 13:07:22.000000000 +0200 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 mduda mduda   4096 2009-08-26 13:07:22.000000000 +0200 Music
drwxr-xr-x  2 mduda mduda   4096 2009-08-26 13:07:22.000000000 +0200 Pictures
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This comes close:

```
stat -l -t "%F %T %z" *
```

but without the sort, columns don't line up and the nanoseconds aren't included. Plus the syntax for file selection is different and other options for `ls` aren't available or are different.

This one might be closer:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf "%M %n %-6u %-6g %6s %TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %TZ %f\n"|sort -k 9
```

In Mac OSX, `gfind` is needed (`brew install gfind`) (and note that the granularity will only be in whole seconds):

> gfind . -maxdepth 1 -printf "%M %n %-6u %-6g %6s %TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %TZ
>   %f\n"|sort -k 9

Comment: Thanks for including a working time format string. In FreeBSD (i.e. TrueNAS) zsh ls, the command is `ls -alD"%F %T%z"` (like your example, but I removed the space before the timezone).

Comment: On macOS Catalina 10.15: `ls -alT`; there doesn't seem to be an option to format the time.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but if you're on OS X you can install coreutils to get the GNU version of `ls`, which includes the `--time-style` option:

```
brew install coreutils
```

Note that by default the utilities installed will be prefixed with `g`, so `ls` becomes `gls`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls --full-time
```

works same as `ls --time-style=full-iso`